# Read blob from google bucket knowing the name of the file

Tags: python, blob, google-bucket

I’m trying to read an excel file in Google bucket by using its name to find it. I have below code to find the latest file in the bucket (file that was added last):

```
bucket_name = 'bucket_name'
blobs = [(blob, blob.updated) for blob in client.list_blobs(bucket_name, prefix ='')]
latest = sorted(blobs, key=lambda tup: tup[1])[-1][0]
latest = latest.name.split('/')
file_name = ''.join(latest)
print(file_name)
```

Then I’m trying to download_as_bytes. However, I can’t do that since file_name is not a blob. Is there any way to find the latest added blob in the google bucket and read so that I could then download_as_bytes? Or is there a way to somehow pass the file_name to find the blob information so that I could download_as_bytes?